# How To Discover RSS Feeds for a given URL

Tags: php, rss, feed, atom-feed

I get a URL from a user. I need to know:
a) is the URL a valid RSS feed?
b) if not is there a valid feed associated with that URL

using PHP/Javascript or something similar

(Ex. http://techcrunch.com fails a), but b) would return their RSS feed)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Found something that I wanted:

Google's [AJAX Feed API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/) has a load feed and lookup feed function (Docs [here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/documentation/reference.html#_intro_fonje)).

a) [Load feed](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://www.digg.com/rss/index.xml) provides the feed (and feed status) in JSON

b) [Lookup feed](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/lookup?v=1.0&q=http://www.techcrunch.com) provides the RSS feed for a given URL

Theres also a find feed function that searches for RSS feeds based on a keyword.

Planning to use this with JQuery's $.getJSON

Comment: Too bad you have to use Google Feeds API for that. RSS has a simple discovery mechanism based on <link> elements in the <head> section. It's very easy to implement and will remove one dependency on Google if you do that.

Answer (score 10):

The [Zend Feed class](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.findFeeds.html) of the **Zend-framework** can automatically parse a webpage and list the available feeds.

Example:

```
$feedArray = Zend_Feed::findFeeds('http://www.example.com/news.html');
```

Answer (score 6):

[This link](http://feedvalidator.org/) will allow you to validate the link against the RSS/Atom specifications using the W3C specs, but does require you to manually enter the url.

There are a number of ways to do this programmatically, depending on your choice of language - in PHP, parsing the file [as valid XML](http://www.contentwithstyle.co.uk/Blog/132/) is a good way to start, then compare it to the [relevant DTD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.schemavalidate.php).

For b), if the link itself isn't a feed, you can parse it and look for a specified feed in the <head> section of the page, searching for a link whose type is "application/rss+xml", e.g:

```
<link rel="alternate" title="RSS Feed" 
    href="http://www.example.com/rss-feed.xml" type="application/rss+xml" />
```

This type of link is the one used by most browsers to "auto-discover" feeds (causing the RSS icon to appear in your address bar)

Answer (score 5):

a) Retrieve it and try to parse it. If you can parse it, it's valid.

b) Test if it's an HTML document (server sent `text/html`) MIME-type. If so, run it through an HTML parser and look for `<link>` elements with RSS feed relations.

Answer (score 4):

For Perl, there is [Feed::Find](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Feed-Find/) , which does automate the discovery of syndication feeds from the webpage. The usage is quite simplicistic:

```
use Feed::Find;
my @feeds = Feed::Find->find('http://example.com/');
```

It first tries the `link` tags and then scans the `a` tags for files named `.rss` and something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing this in a specific language, or do you just want details about the RSS specification?

In general, look for the XML prolog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

followed by an <rss> element, but you might want to validate it as XML, fully validate it against a DTD, or verify that - for example, each URL referred to is valid, etc. More detail would help.

**UPDATE**: Ah - PHP. I've found this library to be pretty useful: [MagpieRSS](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/)