# Obtain the blog feed URL automatically

Tags: c#, rss

Given a blog URL, obtain its RSS feed URL. I know this question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61535/how-to-discover-rss-feeds-for-a-given-url), but I'm looking for a framework independent algorithm, however I'd prefer code in C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look for a

```
<link rel="alternate" type="..." href="..." />
```

tag in the page from the given URL.

The type will be `application/atom+xml` for Atom, `application/rss+xml` for RSS. The href will be the URL for the feed.

Comment: I think you mean "application/rss+xml" and "application/atom+xml".